# Expresión regular para encontrar una línea que no contenga una palabra

Tags: regex

Me preguntaba si es posible encontrar las líneas de texto que no contienen una palabra específica (por ejemplo, "hede") usando una expresión regular.

**Entrada:**

```
hoho
hihi
haha
hede
```

**Salida:**

```
hoho
hihi
haha
```

Comment: Una posible respuesta en este caso: `/(h[a,e,i,o u]){2,}/` https://regex101.com/r/mSMtQm/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes imitar este comportamiento usando *Lookahead* negativo:

```
^((?!hede).)*$
```

Esta expresión regular encontrará cualquier cadena o línea sin un salto de línea, que no contenga la cadena "hede".

- [Ejemplo de la expresión regular aplicada](https://regex101.com/r/S0Hc6D/1)
- [Respuesta original en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)